# cache busting of static assets in angular 5

Tags: caching, angular5, lazy-loading

Hanging around this problem from quite a few days..

I have an angular 5 application, I am using some js files which are present in src/assets/js/*.js of my angular app's project directory. Since to achieve good performance, i am using lazy loading technique for loading of these js files.
I have a script.service.ts file in the app folder which loads the js files, i provide the names of the js files to this service to make it load. I also have a script.store.ts file where i have mapping of the js file names with there paths. Script.service.ts uses this path to load the js file with the mentioned name.

Problem - Now, whenever i change something in my js file and deploy the application, the changes are not getting reflected in the browser since the files are already cached. I have used gulp plugin to append a hash content to these file names with task runner, but i cannot make changes in the code of script.store.ts every time, since the content hash is unique for each file..

I am searching for a solution where i can achieve cache busting having incorporated this lazy loading feature of js files..

I hope i will get the solution soon. Thanks in Advance.